# Double dimension of a variable

Tags: python

It is my first time programming with Python (I used NCL before) and I try to double the longitude dimension of my variables *rad_cool* and *prec*. 
But I have a problem with the syntax of Python and get the error:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

That's my code:

```
n=np.size(time_sat)
m=np.size(lat_sat)
l=np.size(lon_sat)*2
prec_double=[[n],[m],[l]]
rad_cool_double=[[n],[m],[l]]

for j in range(0,720):
    if(j<=359):
      rad_cool_double[:][:][j]=rad_cool[:][:][j]
      prec_double[:][:][j]=prec[:][:][j]
    else:
       rad_cool_double[:][:][j]=rad_cool[:][:][j-np.size(lon_sat)]
       prec_double[:][:][j]=prec[:][:][j-np.size(lon_sat)]
```

Can anyone help me with that?

Cheers,
Leo

Comment: The dimension of rad_cool_double and prec_double is [time=731,lat=180,lon=720]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want `prec_double` and `rad_cool_double` to be numpy arrays. Here you have defined them as lists.

```
 n=731
 m=180
 l=720
 prec_double=[[n],[m],[l]]
```

will result in prec_double  to be a list of

```
[[731], [180], [720]]
```

you want to create these variables as numpy arrays using

```
prec_double = np.zeros([n,m,l])
```

This will fill them with zeros.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to work, but know I get the Error: ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (180,360) into shape (180,720). This makes not much sense for me, because there are two different variables..and the longitude-dimension of prec_double is 720?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it! Had the wrong slicing.

`Not [:][:][j] but [:,:,j]`

Thank you! :)